# No such module 'SwiftSVG' in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, svg

I am a beginner in `iOS` development. I'm going to use `Swift` to develop it. Module downloaded through pod because **SVG image** needs to be used. However, this module is not available. Why do errors occur? And if you want to use this module, can you give me an example of where to put the svg file and how to add it?

**cmd**
[image: cmd]

**pod file**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'stackoverflow' do
  use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftSVG', '~> 2.0'

  # Pods for stackoverflow

  target 'stackoverflowTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'stackoverflowUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

**Viewcontroller.swift**

```swift
import SwiftSVG // No such module 'SwiftSVG'
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var svgimage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


}
```

**image file path**

[image: imagepath]

---

### **Edit from here**

I added the svg file from the asset file, as advised by @Adrian. And we used the command. However, an error will occur.

add **logo_name_01.svg**

[image: svg]

**But error**

[image]

Comment: Are you opening the workspace file and not the project file? Also, you may want to clean your caches and rebuild the project. `shift+option+command+k` followed by `command+b` from the WORKSPACE, not the project file.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian.  The 'shift+option+command+k' command generates an error, but builds using the 'command+b' command will disappear. Is this normal?

Comment: @Adrian And I put the svg file in the image file. How can you do this? Can you give me an example?

Comment: alrighty dude, I got it working with minimal fuss. I posted a step-by-step how I did it. Good luck. (My project name is `DeleteMe`)

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. But I get an error. Can you see which part is the problem? I edited my question. @Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working the first time. Here's what I did:

1. Edit the Podfile to look like this:

   ```
   # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
   platform :ios, '12.0'

   target 'DeleteMe' do
   # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

   # Pods for DeleteMe
   pod 'SwiftSVG', '~> 2.0'

   end
   ```
2. Save and run `pod install`
3. Open the `ProjectName.xcworkspace` file in Xcode 10.3.
4. Command + B to build the project before doing anything.
5. Add an SVG file to the app's data set [following these instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AddingDataSets.html).

5 1/2. `import SwiftSVG`

6. Create a `UIView` on the storyboard and drag an @IBOutlet to the view controller.

   ```
   @IBOutlet var svgView: UIView!
   ```
7. In `viewDidLoad()`, I added the following lines:

   ```
   let netflix = UIView(SVGNamed: "Netflix")
   svgView.addSubview(netflix)
   ```

End result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. But I get an error. Can you see which part is the problem? I edited my question. @Adrian

Comment: the only difference I see between your code and mine is the Podfile. I'd try updating this line in your Podfile from ` platform :ios, '9.0'` to ` platform :ios, '12.0'` or something like that to see if that's where the issue lies. Also, make sure you've opened the workspace, not the project file.

Comment: I changed the Podfile to 12 version like your answer and opened the Workspace file.

Comment: ...and then what happened?

Comment: An error occurs like a picture of a question that I edited.

Comment: That's a new error. The framework loads. Go back over adding the SVG file to the project. I suspect that's where your problem lives. It's DIFFERENT than adding a vanilla png or a pdf to assets. The link I provided in my answer works perfectly. Your original question was the framework didn't load, so please accept this answer.

Comment: Probably. Read the directions in the link I provided and it should work if you've got a valid SVG file.

Answer (score 0):

build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries -> add SwiftSVG.frameWork -> clean build